# RxSwift subscribeOn and observeOn not on the expected background Thread

Tags: rx-swift

I have the following scheduler:

```
let scheduler = ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: .global(qos: .background))
```

tried with:  `observeOn(scheduler)`
also with:   `subscribeOn(scheduler)`

I'm expecting that the callback from the subscribe would be executed on some the background thread, because of the scheduler.

```
func signIn(withExternalUserID userID: UserID, authenticationToken: String) -> Single<QBUUser> {
        let authenticationToken = "Bearer \(authenticationToken)"
        return .create { observable in
            let request = QBRequest.logIn(
                withUserLogin: "\(userID)",
                password: authenticationToken,
                successBlock: { _, user in
                    user.password = QBSession.current.sessionDetails?.token
                    observable(.success(user)) // <- Here we are on the main thread
                }, errorBlock: { [unowned self] in
                    observable(.error(ChatError.signInError(self.resolve(errorResponse: $0))))  // <- same here: main thread
                }
            )
            return Disposables.create {
                request.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

Because the callbacks of the internal API are executed in the main thread, all my subcribes instead of background thread are also executed on the main thread.

```
tokenRequest
      .flatMap { [unowned self] token -> Single<QBUUser> in
           return self.chatService.signIn(withExternalUserID: currentUser.id, authenticationToken: token)
      }
      .flatMap { [unowned self] user -> Single<QBUUser> in
           return self.chatService.connect(user: user).andThen(Single.just(user))
      }
      .observeOn(self.scheduler)
      .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] user in
            self.chatStorage.set(currentQBUser: user, currentUser: currentUser)
            completable(.completed)
            self.loginSempahore.signal()
       }, onError: { [unowned self] error in
            self.chatStorage.unsetCurrentQBUser()
            completable(.error(error))
            self.loginSempahore.signal()
       })
       .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

What is the correct way to force all callbacks from flatMap, and subscribe being executed by background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to force a function to call its callback on a particular thread unless the library gives you the option to do it. Your `successBlock` and `errorBlock` closures will be called on whatever thread `QBRequest.logIn` wants to call them on and there's nothing you can do about that.

That said, the `.observeOn(_:)` operator will transfer the execution to a different thread so in your last code example, your `onNext` and `onError` closures *will* be executed on the `self.scheduler` thread.